# node.js mongodb - collection.find().toArray(callback) - callback doesn't get called

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, database

I am just starting out with mongodb, but I am running into a problem when trying to use .find() on a collection.

I've created a DataAccessObject which opens a specific databate and then lets your perform operations on it. Here is the code:

The **constructor**:

```
var DataAccessObject = function(db_name, host, port){
    this.db = new Db(db_name, new Server(host, port, {auto_reconnect: true}, {}));
    this.db.open(function(){});
}
```

A **getCollection** function:

```
DataAccessObject.prototype.getCollection = function(collection_name, callback) {
    this.db.collection(collection_name, function(error, collection) {
        if(error) callback(error);
        else callback(null, collection);
  });
};
```

A **save** function:

```
DataAccessObject.prototype.save = function(collection_name, data, callback){
    this.getCollection(collection_name, function(error, collection){
        if(error) callback(error);
        else{
            //in case it's just one article and not an array of articles
            if(typeof (data.length) === 'undefined'){
                data = [data];
            }

            //insert to collection
            collection.insert(data, function(){
                callback(null, data);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

And what seems to be the problematic one - **a findAll function**:

```
DataAccessObject.prototype.findAll = function(collection_name, callback) {
    this.getCollection(collection_name, function(error, collection) {
      if(error) callback(error)
      else {
        collection.find().toArray(function(error, results){
            if(error) callback(error);
            else callback(null, results);
        });
      }
    });
};
```

Whenever I try to dao.**findAll(error, callback)**, the **callback** never gets called.
I've narrowed the problem down to the following part of the code:

```
collection.find().toArray(function(error, result){
    //... whatever is in here never gets executed
});
```

I've looked at how other people do it. In fact, I'm following [this tutorial](http://howtonode.org/express-mongodb) very closely. No one else seems to have this problem with colelction.find().toArray(), and it doesn't come up in my searches.

Thanks,
Xaan.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not using the `open` callback so if you are trying to make the `findall` request right after creating the `dao` then it won't be ready.

If your code is like this, it will not work.

```
var dao = new DataAccessObject("my_dbase", "localhost", 27017);

dao.findAll("my_collection",function() {console.log(arguments);});
```

I tested it and it doesn't find records, and it also gives no error. I think it should give an error.

But if you change it so that you give a callback to the constructor, then it should work.

```
var DataAccessObject = function(db_name, host, port, callback){
    this.db = new Db(db_name, new Server(host, port, {auto_reconnect: true}, {}));
    this.db.open(callback);
}
```

And make your code like this.

```
var dao = new DataAccessObject("my_dbase", "localhost", 27017, function() {
    dao.findAll("my_collection",function() {console.log(arguments);});
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I should have kept that in mind. The tutorials I'm following seem to assume that any operations on such a DAO do not happen immediately after its creation. Thanks again!