# Why the callback never gets called when reading all data from MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

I recently updated my machine to the Node.js version 7.5.0 (if I remember well, I was using version 4 before).

One of the applications which worked before doesn't work any longer. The problem could be reproduced like that:

```
var connectionString = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/blog',
    mongojs = require('mongojs'),
    db = mongojs(connectionString, ['articles']),
    dataArticles = db.collection('articles');

db.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('A');
});

db.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('B');
});

dataArticles.find({}).toArray(function (err, articles) {
    console.log('C');
});
```

This code worked fine before the upgrade, but now, none of the callbacks are called. No errors, nothing. The console remains empty.

If I replace the last block by:

```
db.runCommand({ping: 1}, function (err, res) {
    console.log('C');
});
```

the behavior doesn't change.

The code looks very much like the one from [the official documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongojs). There is [a similar question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12078194/240613), but there, the connection to the database is explicitly opened; in my case, similarly to the documentation, I let `mongojs` handle the connection.

Why doesn't it reach the callbacks?

Comment: I just upgraded my Node.js from 7.2.1 to 7.5.0 and this code works for me in both versions. Changed `connectionString` to `mongodb://localhost:27017` and `query` to `{}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a simple issue with the package conflicting with the version of Node.js.

While I updated Node.js and the versions of dependencies, I forgot to run `npm install`, resulting in old packages being still used.

I imagine that there is, somewhere in the old revisions of `mongojs` package, an issue which prevents it from calling callbacks when running on Node.js 7.5. Either the bug is unknown (because nobody tried to run an outdated version of the package on a recent version of Node.js) or it is known and fixed in later revisions.